# Is there a way to name column names or rownames?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, r-colnames, r-rownames

```
, , RE

     Midterm Final mean
A       81.9  75.1 78.5
B       78.3  69.2 73.8
C       79.6  74.4 77.0
mean    79.9  72.9 76.4
```

I'm trying to name the rows and columns so that "Subject" is above the rows "A,B,C, and mean", and "Exam" is above the columns. I'd also like the header to be "Initial = RE" instead of just "RE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct an array with named `dimnames`, pass a named list as the `dimnames` argument of `matrix` or `array`:

```r
x <- array(seq_len(18L), dim = c(3L, 3L, 2L),
           dimnames = list(D1 = letters[1:3], D2 = letters[4:6], D3 = letters[7:8]))
x
## , , D3 = g
## 
##    D2
## D1  d e f
##   a 1 4 7
##   b 2 5 8
##   c 3 6 9
## 
## , , D3 = h
## 
##    D2
## D1   d  e  f
##   a 10 13 16
##   b 11 14 17
##   c 12 15 18
```

To modify an existing array so that it has named `dimnames`, set the `names` attribute of the `dimnames` attribute:

```r
y <- array(seq_len(18L), dim = c(3L, 3L, 2L),
           dimnames = list(letters[1:3], letters[4:6], letters[7:8]))
names(dimnames(y)) <- c("D1", "D2", "D3")

identical(x, y)
## [1] TRUE
```

However, note that `names(dimnames(y)) <- value` will not work if `dimnames(y)` is `NULL`:

```r
z <- array(seq_len(18L), dim = c(3L, 3L, 2L))
names(dimnames(z)) <- c("D1", "D2", "D3")
## Error in names(dimnames(z)) <- c("D1", "D2", "D3") : 
##   attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

To get named but "empty" `dimnames` in the above case, you would have to do something like

```r
dimnames(z) <- list(D1 = NULL, D2 = NULL, D3 = NULL)
```

or equivalently

```r
dimnames(z) <- setNames(vector("list", 3L), c("D1", "D2", "D3"))
```

Now:

```r
z
## , , 1
## 
##       D2
## D1     [,1] [,2] [,3]
##   [1,]    1    4    7
##   [2,]    2    5    8
##   [3,]    3    6    9
## 
## , , 2
## 
##       D2
## D1     [,1] [,2] [,3]
##   [1,]   10   13   16
##   [2,]   11   14   17
##   [3,]   12   15   18
```

It is interesting that we don't see `D3 = 1` and `D3 = 2` in the `print` output. That *might* be a bug - I'd have to ask the people upstairs.